# Code not displaying anything

Tags: python, automation, paramiko

Can someone please help in finding whats wrong with this code. 
Its not display anything

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('135.279.151.56', username='raft',  password='raft01')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('top')

print stdout.readlines()

ssh.close()
```

Comment: probably because `top` command never terminates

Comment: even 'top -n1' is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try 'top -b -n1' 
It should work for you.

-b is for working in batch mode. No inputs are accepted and top quits after -n  number iterations that is 1 here